# Update csv file with awk

Tags: bash, csv, unix

I have a csv which I will update in a daily basis. The format of the csv file is shown below :

```
Name,Priority,UsedBy,Uptime
"server1","3","owner1",100
"server2","3","owner2",200
"server3","3","owner3",300
```

I have written a bash script to update the 4th column value on a daily basis and it works fine. But I would like to simplify the code to a one liner using awk. The uptime value is depended on the server value on the first column. My script will use the following regex to get the uptime value of each server via SSH :

```
ssh $serverName uptime | sed 's/.*up \([^,]*\), .*/\1/'
```

I am still in the process of figuring it out and will post here to speed up the resolution time. Any ideas or help given will be greatly appreciated.

**Latest updates**

I tried the codes shown below but to no avail :

```
#!/bin/bash

uptime() {
    myUptime=$(ssh $1 uptime | sed 's/.*up \([^,]*\), .*/\1/')
    echo $myUptime
}

export -f uptime

awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{value=system("bash  -c '\''uptime "$1"'\''") ;$4=value}1' temp.csv
```

and also the following output:

```
[root@masterserver tmp]# ./tempScript.sh
"Name","Priority","UsedBy","Uptime"
 100 days
 "server1","3","owner1",0

 200 days
 "server2","3","owner2",0

 300 days
 "server3","3","owner3",0
```

csv file is still the same with old data with no amendments at all.

Comment: Are you saying the `1`, `2`,`3` in `Name` will correspond to `100`,`200`, etc under Uptime?

Comment: In this example the uptime of server1 is 100 days and server2 is 200 days and server3 is 300 days. Tomorrow server1 will be 101 days and server2 is 201 days and server3 is 301 days. If any of the server is rebooted along the way then the uptime will be 0 or 1 days. When the cron is run daily.

Answer (score 0):

The `system` call returns the command's [exit status](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/I_002fO-Functions.html), but you can use [getline](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Getline_002fVariable_002fPipe.html) like so:

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}NR>1{
"uptime" | getline tmp
split(tmp, utarray, " ")
print $1","$2","$3","utarray[3]}' temp.csv
```

Note that `"uptime"` is the command that gets executed, resulting in the variable `tmp` being set to something like `11:09:00 up 1 day, 22:21,  1 user,  load average: 0.00, 0.00, 0.00`. Then, the awk built-in function `split` turns `tmp`'s value into an array `utarray` using the space as a separator. In the last line the output record is assembled.